# Reading xml injava

Tags: java, xml

I am trying to read the below item from xml using java -

Xml is-

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Item1>
  <Field>content1</Field>   
   <Row>
    <Item>3</Item>
    <id>33</id>
    <content>&lt;script type="text/javascript" xml:space="preserve"&gt;
&lt;/script&gt;&lt;span style="FONT-WEIGHT: bold"&gt;Access to $data&lt;/span&gt;&lt;br /&gt;
The $data is&amp;#160;&amp;#160;the$word oneas, $companyname's  our website - $link.&lt;br /&gt;
&lt;br /&gt;
recommend on your $name ase  or visit one of our $name dealer - $dealer.&lt;br /&gt;
&lt;br /&gt;
&lt;span style="FONT-WEIGHT: bold"&gt;Meters&lt;/span&gt;&lt;br /&gt;accurate. earlier..&lt;br /&gt;
</content>
  </Row>
  </Item1>
```

I am able to read the content but its coming with the special characters as well.

While reading the content want to remove the special characters like inplace of &lt it should be <.

Can some one suggest me how should i proceed.

I am reading the xml as follows-

```
public class ReadXml {

  public static void main(String argv[]) {
    try { 
    File fXmlFile = new File("test.xml");
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    /*InputSource is = new InputSource(fXmlFile);
    is.setEncoding("UTF-8");*/
    Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);    
    doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
    System.out.println("Root element :" + doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());
    NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("Row");
    System.out.println("----------------------------");
    for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {
        Node nNode = nList.item(temp);
        System.out.println("\nCurrent Element :" + nNode.getNodeName());
        if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
            Element eElement = (Element) nNode;
            //System.out.println("Staff id : " + eElement.getAttribute("item"));
            System.out.println("Id : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("id").item(0).getTextContent());
        }
    }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: How are you reading it - which of the many XML parsers and libraries are you using? Please format your XML so it is readable

Comment: NO DONT ADD CODE INTO THE COMMENT DONT DO IT AAHH

Comment: That info should be in the question

Comment: @mark i have added the code like how i am trying to read the xml.

Comment: Does not know the meaning of "While reading the content want to remove the special characters like inplace of &lt it should be <." @user3568243 can you explain it or give a example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use java xerces library. I used SAX parser it was automatically converting &lt; to < and &gt; >
http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-j/